# Plot data with pgfplots such that each data point corresponds every second x value

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to plot data from a txt file using pgfplots. My code for that is

```
\pgfplotstableread{data/Full_data_matrix.txt}{\data}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=Time,
    ylabel=Carrier density [$1/\si{\meter\cubed}$]
    \addplot [black,very thick] table [x={Time}, y={A}] {\data};
    \addplot [red,very thick] table [x={Time}, y={B}] {\data};
    \addplot [green,very thick] table [x={Time}, y={C}] {\data};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Carrier concentration created by pulses at different wavelengths}
\end{figure}
```

Now I have twice as many points for `Time`, `A` and `B` as for `C`, but I know that each point of `C` corresponds to every second point in time. Is there an easy way to tell `pgfplots` this without having to introduce a new time scale for `C`?

An example for the data file is

```
Time  A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  3
2  3  3  5
3  4  4  7
4  5  5  0 
5  6  6  0 
6  7  7  0
```

Here I would expect all lines to be exactly the same, but due to a smaller amount of data points I have to stretch `C` somehow.

Comment: Could you add the `Full_data_matrix.txt` file (or at least the top part which is representative) to the code, so we can have a look how it currently looks like?

Comment: `\addplot [green,very thick] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={C}] {\data};`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: If my time scale is significantly different, this will plot the graphs at different positions in the figure (f.ex. if the time goes from -5 to -1, then the graph for C will still be plotted from 0 to 4)

Comment: `\coordindex-5` then.

Comment: If using the correct values (instead of -5), that works @TorbjørnT.

Comment: After re-reading your question I don't really see how that could work properly.

Comment: Why could it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate an x-value based on row number or specific column values using `x expr={<some calculation>}` instead of `x=<column>`. To get the row number of the table (counting from 0) use `\coordindex`, to get the value of a specific column use `\thisrow{<columnname>}`. In the specific example you show, `x expr={2*\thisrow{Time}}` should work, but it should be combined with something like `restrict x to domain=-1:7.4` to filter away the zeros at the end of the column. (If you replace the zeros in the data table with `NaN` you don't have to do that filtering.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} % if you don't have a compat setting already
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
Time  A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  3
2  3  3  5
3  4  4  7
4  5  5  0 
5  6  6  0 
6  7  7  0
}{\data}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      small,
      minor tick num=1,
      xlabel=Time,
      ylabel={Carrier density [$1/\si{\meter\cubed}$]} % note braces around the whole ylabel
    ]

    \addplot [black,very thick] table [x={Time}, y={A}] {\data};
    \addplot [red,very thick] table [x={Time}, y={B}] {\data};
    \addplot [green,
              very thick,
              restrict x to domain=-1:7.4 % to filter away the last three rows
             ]
            table [
              x expr={2*\thisrow{Time}}, % an appropriate expression for this case 
              y={C}
              ] {\data};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Carrier concentration created by pulses at different wavelengths}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```